# Как правильно проверить input.focus() на строгое равенство null и undefined (React, TS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

При строгой проверке на null и undefined выходит ошибка. Я правильно понимаю, что нужно указать тип? В каком месте его указывать, что-бы исправить ошибку? Ошибка выходит когда я возвращаю return  в обоих условиях

```js
const textInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement|null>(null)
    if (props.active) {
        if (typeof textInput === "undefined") {
            return
        }
        if (textInput === null) {
            return
        }
        textInput.current?.focus()
    }

return(
 <input type="text" ref={textInput} />
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы просто проверить, что `textInput.current` существует можно сделать так:

```
if (textInput.current) {
  textInput.current.focus();
}
```

Не нужно проверять отдельно на `null` и `undefined`.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

type AppProps = {
  active: boolean;
};

export const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
  const textInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.active) {
      if (textInput.current) {
        textInput.current.focus();
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return <input type="text" ref={textInput} />;
};
```